# Links in Visual Studio Comments?

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, comments

When investigating effective methods of documenting our VB .NET project, by experimentation I discovered that I can make a comment like

```
'See the file at file://path_to_file
```

and I can then ctrl-click on this link to bring up the file in a new tab.  Is this feature and perhaps other capabilities of Visual Studio comments documented anywhere?  I would like to make a system of documentation consisting of an html pages that link to code, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about linking back to the code from documentation but you could use XML comments and try [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/). I have used it once or twice with XML comments in C#, but rumour has it that it can be used with VB.Net too.
Basically you comment your code and then setup a Sandcastle project pointing to your VS project, and it builds your documentation for you. You can choose output to be either HTML Help 1.x (.CHM) or HTML Help 2.x (.HxS). Also, because it is XML based you can customise the output by altering the (or creating your own) XSL files.